# Is it possible to extend LVDS and SPI to 3 meter distance

Tags: spi, high-speed, lvds

In a hardware design application, we need to extend below signals to 3-meter cable.

1. LVDS data @ 720Mbps
2. Clock: 72Mhz
3. SPI signals

So, I wanted to know

1. Is it possible to extend above signal to 3-meter distance via cable? What are the pros and cons of extending cable to 3 meter?
2. If yes can please suggest some cable.

Thank you!!

Comment: That's quite similar to HDMI - fast differential signals with an I2C side channel. You may have to keep the SPI slow.

Answer (score 3):

If the SPI data is in one direction only then yes, it can be done. The problem with bi-directional SPI is that reading SPI data back from a slave (remote device) requires that the clock doesn't get too much shifted or the data returned becomes unreadable.

At a master clock of 72 MHz, the period is only 13.9 ns and if the overall delay from sender to receiver back to sender approaches anything like half this time then the sender (master clock generator) is unable to adequately read the data returned due to the accumulated delays.

So, given that signals will propagate at about 5 ns per metre (light is 3.333 ns per metre), bidirectional SPI at a clock rate of 72 MHz will start to be unreadable at just over 1 metre.

However, if the data is "send only" then providing the SPI clock and data is driven down two coax cables correctly\$^1\$ and line receivers are used at the slave-end then the distance that can be achieved is limited only by the cable quality. Hundreds of metres can be achieved with good coax.

> LVDS data @ 720Mbps

This can be done providing you embed the clock with the data either by Manchester encoding or scrambling techniques - I've transmitted data (using proper line drivers and terminators) over 50 metres without too much hassle at this sort of speed but, it's down to using good coax (75 ohm 11 mm or greater OD) or good twisted pair cable.

---

\$^1\$ By "correctly" I mean using proper coax drivers with line terminators or maybe even using balanced line drivers and screened twisted pair (plus terminators).

Comment: Yeah, Manchester encoding his LVDS data sounds like the best bet here -- also, for a point-to-point link, LVDS makes a perfectly cromulent physical layer for SPI...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel how very simpsonesque and embiggenated of you to say so LOL.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to tunnel those signals through something more robust and more isolated than LVDS and single-ended SPI for such a long run. At 3 meter run the crosstalk can be fairly significant, and inductively coupled high voltage spikes are often real concerns. A cheap solution would be tunneling those signal through Ethernet, using a SBC that is capable of handling that data rate.

You will have to leave the clock out and generate a separate clock on the receiving end of the cable. SPI traffic can be tunneled using a TCP connection. As of the LVDS, depend on your signal type, you may be able to send a compressed form of it (if it is a video feed) to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to put this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation!

HDMI cable would be my first choice if I had it lying around.

Ethernet cable would also be a decent second choice.

If the data is uni-directional, the most important job you have is very careful impedance matching of all the components, to minimize the signal distortion!