# Does long SPI lanes require extra attention?

Tags: spi

I am designing 3 SPI slave devices that are fairly far away from the host, The SPI communicates at 50MHz (Max) at 3.3v

[image]

Slave 3 is an off board device where it is connected to the board by a ribbon cable. The slave devices are just straight up connected to the master exempt for slave 3 which have a tvs diode.

Does the SPI bus needs special attention? is it okay to just straight up connect them ?

Comment: You may have to run Slave 3 at a lower speed off a separate SPI bus.

Comment: You will want terminations

Comment: [Is it possible to extend LVDS and SPI to 3 meter distance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272520/is-it-possible-to-extend-lvds-and-spi-to-3-meter-distance/272525#272525) - this might help you understand the problem with bidirectional SPI - if the slaves are not transmitting back then it will be a lot more reliable.

Comment: @BrianDrummond sadly there is only 1 SPI bus, if it actually has a problem running at that speed, i will just have to keep switching the SPI clock when trying to communicate with  slave 3.

Comment: @DKNguyen It seems that SPI termination is a rabbit hole. but what i understood is to place a resistor inline with the SPI buss, the value will have to varry, but that would be easier to solve as i can just swap the resistor on the board. But where do i place this resistor ? befor the spi bus splits or near slave 3? Whith capacitance such a problem i guess i should reduce my traces to as thin as possible

Comment: @Andyaka So the ribbon cable might become my weakpoint, though im no where near 1meter do you still think this will become a problem ?

Comment: @Jakequin have you got bidirectional SPI?

Comment: Also consider the timing skew of the three devices due to distance. Electricity [travels ~0.7c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_electricity) so a [meter in 1/0.7*3.3ns = 4.7ns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light). 20cm-5cm = 15cm. 1m/15cm = 66.67. 4.7ns/66.67 = 70.5ps. Probably not enough to cause issues but just be aware distance = delay.

Comment: @Andyaka im not sure if by bidirectional SPI you mean 3 wire SPI, I am using 4 wire SPI  - MISO, MOSI, CS, SCLK.

Comment: One thing you can do to help the termination nightmare is to route that net as a single line rather than a trident with three different length stubs, even if that line is a little longer. (Then you might find a series termination RIGHT at the send end of each line is enough).  But I doubt that's good enough for 50MHz.

Comment: @rdtsc I believe you may have confused mm and cm? 15cm *7 > 1m.

Comment: @Jakequin Long branches make it a lot trickier. Series termination, which is resistor placed as close as possible to the driver, is probably what you will end up using just due to simplicity. I guess what I'm saying is, leave positions on each PCB for a series resistor on both driver and receiver. Even the receiver in this case due to the termination nightmare in case you need them to make some kind of compromise between devices due to branching. You can also add in positions for parallel termination resistors at the destination as well in case you need them. That way you have options.

Comment: Oh yes Brian, goof there. 1m/15cm = 6.667. 4.7ns/6.667 = 0.705ns.  0.705*100/20ns = 3.525% delay of 20ns cycle (one way.)

Comment: Do you actually need 50MHz or anything close to it? At lower speeds (under 1MHz) this would be fine with just some small series resistance.

Comment: Also, switching clock speed per device is not that big a deal, only takes a few cycles

Answer (score 1):

In my case a SPI connection (initially separate loose wires) did not work reliably until I noticed that the clock lead really "likes to be" near the ground lead - suddenly starts working much better. But it was a slightly larger distance, about 30 cm wires between the two separate PCBs.

In response, I have used the ribbon cable with every second wire grounded, and all four SPI signals in between. The connectivity is now reliable. Maybe I have over tried with the measure so draconian but at least one less thing to worry about in my design.

Comment: At what speed? for comparison with the question's 50MHz.

Comment: The speed was irregular in my case, because I was driving all signals directly from C++ on Linux through GPIO in userspace.  The tlc5947 chip is kind of SPI but not completely. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520886/can-i-operate-tlc5947-24-channel-12-bit-pwm-led-driver-by-just-manipulating-gpi on that project.